# How to reach li tags in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html-lists, addeventlistener, queryselector

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="lies" name="lies"  >Adem</li>
        <li class="lies" name="lies"  >Adem1</li>
        <li class="lies" name="lies"  >Adem2</li>
        <li class="lies" name="lies"  >Adem3</li>
        <li class="lies" name="lies"  >Adem4</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="button">Add name</button>

<script>
    const listChild = document.querySelectorAll('.lies');
    listChild.addEventListener('click', () => {
        listChild.parentNode.removeChild('listChild');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

(l know only HTML, css , javascript. so don't try to answer with jquery. l won't get it)
l want when l click on li*s to disappear. but code doesn't work properly.

Comment: It's because you're using `querySelectorAll` which returns a list of Nodes

Answer (score 0):

Is this was you're trying to do?

```js
const listChildren = document.querySelectorAll('.lies');


listChildren.forEach(function(listChild){
  listChild.addEventListener('click',function(event){
    event.target.parentNode.removeChild(event.target);
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input">
<ul class="list">
    <li class="lies" name="lies"  >Adem</li>
    <li class="lies" name="lies"  >Adem1</li>
    <li class="lies" name="lies"  >Adem2</li>
    <li class="lies" name="lies"  >Adem3</li>
    <li class="lies" name="lies"  >Adem4</li>
</ul>
<button class="button">Add name</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) the querySelectorAll function returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) of matching DOM elements. Note that a node list is like an array in that you can iterate over it using forEach but it is not an array.
2) The [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) function takes a dom element as a parameter. What you have is a string that happens to have the same contents as your variable name.

Although as I mentioned you can iterate over a NodeList with a forEach I'll just use an old-school for loop.

Note that I also added a click handler for your button to append the text in the text box as a new name at the end of the list.

```js
const listChildren = document.querySelectorAll('.lies');
for (let i = 0; i < listChildren.length; i++) {
  let item = listChildren[i];
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
  });
}

let itemList = document.querySelector('.list');
let addNameBtn = document.querySelector('button');
addNameBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let newNameNode = document.querySelector('.input');
  let newName = newNameNode.value;
  // only continue if there is text in the input box (i.e. don't allow adding blank names)
  if(newName && newName != ''){
    // creast ethe new li dom element to hold the name and set the class and name 
    var li=document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = newName
    li.className = "lies";
    li.name = "lies";
    // register click handler 
    li.addEventListener('click', () => {
      li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
    });
    //Append the new name to the list.
    itemList.appendChild(li);
    // blank out the input to allow fo rentry of the next name
    newNameNode.value = "";
  }

});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="lies" name="lies"  >Adem</li>
        <li class="lies" name="lies"  >Adem1</li>
        <li class="lies" name="lies"  >Adem2</li>
        <li class="lies" name="lies"  >Adem3</li>
        <li class="lies" name="lies"  >Adem4</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="button">Add name</button>


</body>
</html>
```